# "If I'll be there" correctness and first conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

First, are the following sentences correct?

1. *"If I'll be there, I'll do <something>."* - That's how google translates my sentence
2. *"If I am there, I'll do <something>."* - I tried to create a sentence in first conditional.

If sentence number one is correct, why is it like that? I know that for example *"If it will rain, I will do <something>"* is incorrect, but it has similar structure for me.

Comment: Don't assume Google is always correct.

Comment: Right.  Scrap sentence #1.  Do you have any idea how hard it is to write a translation program?  We can't expect it to do a very good job (at this point in history -- but maybe some day).

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is not correct traditionally (according to grammar books), however, in colloquial language I keep hearing "If I would..." as well from native speakers, which is the same type of "mistake" (2nd conditional). So it looks like language usage is changing slowly, and "If I will" is starting to catch on. Two generations ago the usage of "I will" instead of "I shall" was considered ungrammatical, but now it is the norm; perhaps we are witnessing a similar change with "If I will", and in a couple of years the grammatical rules for conditional sentences will also soften up and allow alternatives.

So the first sentence is not officially correct, but it is gradually becoming acceptable.

Comment: The language is changing (or has changed, in some regions of the U.S.) to make *"if I would"* acceptable. But that's not the same as *"if I will"*; I don't believe I hear that.