# First Conditional Sentences

Tags: conditional-constructions

In order to make a first conditional sentence, I need to build my sentence this way:

> **If** the train **is** delayed, **I'll** be late

or

> **If** it **snows**, I **won't** go to the party.

I've read though in the following link - ["If I'll be there" correctness and first conditional](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106213/if-ill-be-there-correctness-and-first-conditional) - that

> "The language is changing (or has changed, in some regions of the
>   U.S.) to make "if I would" acceptable. But that's not the same as "if
>   I will".

There wasn't any example following that but I understood from it that I can say - for instance - If it would snow, I won't go to the party.

Nevertheless, There's this song "**To the Moon and Back**" of Savage Garden (I know that they are Australians) which goes like this:

> "I would fly to the moon and back if you'll be my baby".

So I searched about this structure online and found a reference to this only on Cambridge dictionary: in https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/conditionals-if

In this link, there is a section called "**Conditional clauses with will or would**". This section explains that such usage is used when we actually reply to something stated before (or in order to indicate willingness or unwillingness to do something).

So for example, If someone tells me

> "I'll be happy if you stay at home tonight".

Then I can reply,

> "If it **would/will** make you happy, I will stay at home tonight".

Since it's a British dictionary and since the above mentioned citation of the song is Australian English if you will, thus the usage can vary, is it also the only case in which I can use this structure (If I'd...I'll) in American English or is it different in that the if sentence doesn't have to refer to what was stated previously (Or to indicate willingness or unwillingness)?

Secondly, can I even say "If I'll" in American English or can I only say "if I'd"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The standard pairings are ***I'll do it if you will***, and ***I'd do it if you did***. But I think Americans are more likely than Brits to use uncontracted *If you **would** have done it, so would I*. Personally I'd only ever use contracted *If **you'd** have done it...* in such contexts, where I'm quite happy to suppose ***'d*** stands for ***had*** rather than ***would***. But (American?) grammarians aren't necessarily keen on my position there.

Comment: ...but I'd agree with those strict grammarians as regards *I **would** fly you to the moon and back if you **will** be my baby*. It's awkward at best. The auxiliary verbs should both be either ***will*** or ***would*** - it makes no difference which you choose, but for consistency, you should stick to the same choice for both, in such "parallel" constructions.

Comment: In your first comment you mean that whenever you say "If you'd done it, I would've as well", the 'd contraction stands for the word had ("If you had done it...") while Americans tend to refer to the d' in that sentence as if it stands for the word would?

Comment: That's right, yes. But no less an authority than [Prof John Lawler over on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62490/2637) says *I know of at least one other case of someone's unpacking it as "If I **had** have lost you", which **makes my teeth itch.*** So clearly *he* doesn't like the way I see it. Personally, if ever I encounter uncontracted ***would*** in such contexts, my first thought is always that I'm dealing with a (usually European, particularly *German*) non-native Anglophone.